# EaselJS mouse events not working - debug canvas appears to be catching them

Tags: html, events, canvas, coffeescript, easeljs

I'm building an app in **HTML5**, using **CreateJS (EaselJS)**, **Box2D** and written in CoffeeScript using Browserify (built with Gulp).

I've just spent the best part of a half a day beating my head against the keyboard trying to work out why I couldn't get my EaselJS events working. Window/document events were fine. Any and all EaselJS event just did nothing. It turns out **the debug canvas was trapping them, overlaying invisibly**.

I accidentally discovered this eventually by toggling the debug canvas on and off which allowed the events to get though and they started responding.

So now, my question is: what's the best way to handle events so that they will work

**a) without me first toggling the debug canvas**, and

**b) when debug is active, how can I pass events through to the main canvas below so that it can handle them?**

Is that possible? It would be ideal that even with debug draw on, mouseevents worked as normal.

HTML is this:

```
<body>
  <canvas id="arcade"></canvas>
  <canvas id="debug"></canvas>
    <button id="toggle-debug">Toggle Debug</button>

    <script src="compiled.js"></script>
</body>
```

My app class sets up events calling bindEvents from its constructor thus:

```
bindEvents: =>
  # Pause when window is blurred
  window.addEventListener 'blur', @setPaused
  # Play when window is focused
  window.addEventListener 'focus', @setPlay
  # Toggle showing/hiding of the Debug <canvas>
  document.getElementById('toggle-debug').onclick = @toggleDebug

toggleDebug: =>
  @showDebug = !@showDebug
  # Shows/hides Debug canvas
  Universe.debug.canvas.style.display = (if @showDebug then 'block' else 'none')

setPlay: =>
  @play = true
  createjs.Ticker.setPaused false

setPaused: =>
  @play = false
  createjs.Ticker.setPaused true
```

My objects (which contain box2d body in @body and easelJS display objects in @view) set up their events in a similar method, e.g.

```
bindEvents: ->
  @view.on "click", () =>  alert("ball #{@options.id} clicked")
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the DOM does not provide a good way to ignore mouse events on an object, or pass them through. You can however use the `Stage.nextStage` property.

1. Create an EaselJS stage, and pass in your debug canvas
2. Set the `nextStage` property on the new Stage to the stage that is below that one.

Here is a quick code sample:

```
var stage2 = new createjs.Stage("DebugCanvasId");
stage2.nextStage = stage1;
```

EaselJS 0.7.0 added the `nextStage` property, but the very latest NEXT version in GitHub ***vastly*** improved support for this. There is a demo in GitHub where you can see this working (TwoStages.html). Here is the online sample: http://createjs.com/Demos/EaselJS/TwoStages.html

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved part a) by changing the html to

```
<canvas id="debug" style="display: none;"></canvas>
```

I also tried doing this programmatically in the game (toggling the debug twice) but for some reason it didn't work. I don't know why.

I'd still like to get an answer to B though. How to pass mouse events though the debug canvas to the one below.